# cakephp $this->Auth->identify() always return false

Tags: authentication, cakephp

I have two environments in **cakephp 3.9** , both same code and same SO etc... Both in AWS hosted. I have created an API that works fine in staging but not in production, I always get FALSE when the user login with the email and pwd to get the JWT token. The weird thing it is that it works perfectly in the same environment in staging.

In the endpoint, I have this

```
 /**
 * Get JWT token
 */
public function token()
{
    $user = $this->Auth->identify();
    $roleQuery = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('UsersRoles');

    // Get user role
    $role = $roleQuery
    ->find()
    ->select(['role_id'])
    ->where(['user_id' => $user['id']])
    ->first();

    if (!$user) {
        // throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid login details');
        $this->set([
           
            'success' => false,
            'data' => [
                "code" => 401,
                'message' => 'Invalid login details',
            ],
            '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']

        ]);
    }  else{
        $tokenId  = base64_encode(32);
        $issuedAt = time();
        $key = Security::salt();
        // $email = $user['email'];
        $this->set([
            'msg' => 'Login successfully',
            'success' => true,
            // 'user' => $user,
            'data' => [
                'token' => JWT::encode([
                    'alg' => 'HS256',
                    'id' => $user['id'],
                    'sub' => $user['id'],
                    'iat' => time(),
                    'exp' =>  time() + 86400,
                ],
                $key)
            ],
            '_serialize' => ['success', 'data', 'key']
        ]);
    }
}
```

}

And the configuration for this environment

```
'Api' => [
        'auth' => [
            'storage' => 'Memory',
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email'
                    ],
                ],
                'ADmad/JwtAuth.Jwt' => [
                    'parameter' => 'token',
                    'userModel' => 'Users',
                    // 'scope' => ['Users.status' => 1],
                    'fields' => [
                        'id' => 'id'     
                    ],
                    'queryDatasource' => true
                ]
            ],
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => false,
            'checkAuthIn' => 'Controller.initialize'
        ],
    ],
```

In the ApiController I have these two methods to load the components etc...

```
  public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Security');

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', Configure::read('Api.auth'));

        $this->Auth->allow([
            'token'
        ]);
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event): void
    {
        $this->Security->setConfig('unlockedActions', [
            'token'
        ]);
    }
```

I always get the same response in production

```
{
    "success": false,
    "data": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Invalid login details"
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty much impossible for anyone here to tell, you'll have to debug this further on your own I'm afraid. Like, what credentials are being sent, what queries are being issued, what data is present in the DB, what authenticator is failing and where exactly it bails out in its authentication logic, etc.

Comment: Yes, I understand mate, I already did all of this. Credentials are 100% sure correct, the query is the same in staging and in production, same code, same environment, but I know is not easy for someone to help. I will post the solution when I'll found it. I feel that something in the Auth component should be different in production because in staging this method does not return false, but at the moment I did not find it, and because it is in production, and it is an endpoint, debug it is not easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a few hours I fixed the problem. It was a very very stupid thing, I just forgot to add the **https** protocol to the URL in Rester (plugin similar to Postman) before call the endpoint, that's it!!!.